# Anaconda Jupyter notebooks - How to change default directory for my .ipynb scripts?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

New to Anaconda Jupyter notebooks. All my Python and R files are writing to default directory and I haven't see 'Save to different directory option' in notebooks.

I like to change from `C:\Users\xxxx` to some other C directory for book keeping.

Please help.

Comment: On the initial screen, you can create (and delete) and change folders. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for that info. Now I can create my own folder and save those files in those folders. I will consider this as answer to this question. :-)